# Any way to virtualize my smartphone needs?

Tags: virtualization, android

Some services require me to use a smartphone supporting their apps. For instance my banks (logins need to be approved through their official app), whatsapp etc.

I want to be independent from a phone running Android or iOS.

I wish to virtualize those systems away, and be able to use the aforementioned apps at any time, from any computer, via the internet. Even when I don't have a physical phone with me.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Whatever solution, it must be stable and reliable (it should still be working even in 10 years), able to virtualize camera and microphone (e.g. to scan QR Codes using a computer's webcam) and accessible from any device via the internet.

---

Are there Android VPS out there?

Alternatively, are there lightweight Android app emulators I can run on my Linux VPS?
I tried a few (anbox, android emulator, genymotion) on my x86 VPS, but they feel unreliable (anbox), take way too much RAM (android emulator, genymotion), are too slow (android emulator), gave me issues to virtualize cam and mic (anbox, genymotion), don't support ARM apps (anbox, genymotion), are hard-ish to install and migrate (anbox, android emulator)... I didn't manage to run any of them on my ARM systems.

Comment: There are a couple votes to close it as off-topic. What stackexchange site would be more appropriate for this question?

Comment: Did you try to actually look for a solution? What ARM systems do you have? Part of the idea of those applications is usually that you're in possession of the device that makes the second factor for authentication purposes accessible.

Comment: So basically you want an Android phone with reliable network connection and remote desktop?

Comment: Even the newest Android phones don’t have guarantee support for 10 years.  Your going to be hard pressed to find a VPS that not only supports Android but has the Google Platform (which I assume you want).  Any event service recommendations are out of scope here at Super User

Comment: Yeah, basically I would like an android phone (or just the apps it can run) that... 1: doesn't run on special hardware (there's no phone that can break - you can just copy it on a new host and run it). 2: I can access it via network (e.g. via VNC or whatever) and send camera input to it via network.

Comment: I tried to run android emulators on an ODROID-C2 (ARMv8) running Linux, with no success.

Comment: And I don't need a guarantee for 10 years... If I take an image of a virtual machine that I made 10 years ago, it still works nowadays. I want something like that. It's OK if I'm stuck with old virtual hardware and with an old version of android, but I want it to be able to run forever -- some of the android emulators seem to "break" when you update them: that's what I want to avoid

Comment: Even if your Android flavor runs forever, your apps won't support it forever and their vendors won't support old versions that work on your VPS forever. Some popular apps have already dropped support for Marshmallow (Android 6) which is 4 years old. KitKat (4.4) is 6 years old and has major app compatibility problems.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you consider trying to use the Android emulator that's bundled with the official Android SDK?  Not sure if the apps in question will let you use it for 2FA, but most stuff should work fine.  If you can get that working, you just need a regular VPS and something to transfer images to the virtual 'camera'.

Comment: @gronostaj: sure, I agree with what you're saying, I probably phrased it wrongly. What I meant to say is: I want a stable android environment, I don't want something that breaks (and requires to be reinstalled, and to re-authenticate the various apps) when you upgrade the VM or change minor settings.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: you mean the Android Emulator? Yes, I got it working on my local computers and managed to fake the cam (i.e. use with it my `/dev/video0`). I'm wondering if there are any alternatives though: Android Emulator takes *a lot* of RAM and CPU time and my current VPSs aren't strong enough... I'd need a quite powerful Linux VPS just for it. That's why I'm wondering whether there's anything like an Android VPS or some lighter software to achieve the same...

Comment: You might want to look into running AOSP directly in QEMU then, though I seriously doubt that some of the apps you want to use will work under such a setup (it's effectively going to look like a rooted device with no SIM card from the perspective of an app, and I know quite a few that will refuse to run on such systems for security or DRM reasons (for example, Netflix)).